# Read-only System.Xml.XmlElement

Tags: .net, xml

Is it possible to easily return a read-only `System.Xml.XmlElement`, such that its attributes and childs cannot be modified?

I suggest the [XmlNode.IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.isreadonly.aspx) should be used.
For example,

```
System.Xml.XmlElement xml = ...;
//this line does not compile because the IsReadOnly property is read only
xml.IsReadOnly = true; 
return xml;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to wrap it up in your own class/struct to expose this behavior.

Comment: What is your conclusion based on? Why is the `XmlNode.IsReadOnly` property there and where is it used?

Comment: you shouldn't expect anything to behave you want it to.